# A condemning alphametic

Tags: no-computers, alphametic

- Every question mark and every letter stands for a base-10 digit
- Different letters stand for different digits
- Question marks are placeholders and stand for arbitrary digits (such digits also may occur for letters)
- Leading digits are always non-zero.

  ```
           SIN
          * IN
        -------
          ????
          U?S
        -------
         ?EVIL
  ```

Which digit does each letter represent?
(Please present the full analysis how these digits can be determined.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is

> There is one valid solution which is $S=4, I=2, N=7, U=8, E=1, V=5, L=9$

Formatting as above

> 427 
>    *   27 
>  --------- 
>    2989 
>    854 
>  --------- 
>  11529

Proof

> First we note that $N \times N \equiv L (\bmod 10)$ so immediately we cannot have $N=0,1,5,6$ as then $L=N$ which is not permitted. Also important is $I \times N \equiv S (\bmod 10)$ **(1)** 
> We can thus consider the problem for different values of $N$. In the following, let $M_i$ represent the $i$th digit in the first multiplication (reading left to right) 
>  $N=2 \Rightarrow L=4 \Rightarrow M_3 + S \equiv I (\bmod 10)$ and we must have $M_3 = S$ but then from **(1)** above that means that $4S \equiv 2I \equiv S (\bmod 10)$ which means $S=0$ and this cannot be since it is a leading digit. 
>  $N=3 \Rightarrow L=9 \Rightarrow M_3 = S$ and using **(1)** we must have $6S \equiv 3I \equiv S (\bmod 10)$ which allows $S=2,4,6,8$ paired with $I=4,8,2,6$ respectively. Clearly, since the second multiplication has one less digit than the first, we must have $I < N$ so we can rule out all but the third of these possibilities but then $623 \times 2$ has four digits instead of three so this won't work. 
>  $N=4 \Rightarrow L=6 \Rightarrow M_3 = S+1$ which means that $8S+4 \equiv 4I \equiv S (\bmod 10)$ which means $S=8$ and $I=7$ but this doesn't work since we must have $I<N$. 
>  $N=7 \Rightarrow L=9 \Rightarrow M_3 \equiv S+4 (\bmod 10)$ which means that $14S+28 \equiv 7I \equiv S(\bmod 10)$ or more simply $3S \equiv 2(\bmod 10)$ which gives $S=4$ and $I=2$. This gives a **valid solution** with additionally $U=8, E=1, V=5$ 
>  $N=8 \Rightarrow L=4 \Rightarrow M_3 \equiv S+6 (\bmod 10)$ which means that $16S + 48 \equiv 8I \equiv S (\bmod 10)$ or more simply $5S \equiv 2 (\bmod 10)$ which has no solutions. 
>  Finally, $N=9 \Rightarrow L=1 \rightarrow M_3 \equiv S+8 (\bmod 10)$ which gives us $18S+72 \equiv 9I \equiv S(\bmod 10)$ or more neatly $7S \equiv 8 (\bmod 10)$ which gives $S=4$ and $I=6$ but this gives four digits in the second multiplication instead of three. 
>  Having checked all the cases, we find there is only one valid solution.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

> $S=4, I=2, N=7, U=8, E=1, V=5, L=9$

Proof:

> I is not 1, since $SIN*I = U?S$
>  I*S + carriage from I*I < 10.  So I * S < 10.
>  This means
>  [S, I] can be one of [2,3], [2,4], [3,2], [4,2].
>  Since N*N ends in L it means N cannot be one of 0,1,5,6.
>
>  For SIN = 23N, the biggest possible value is
>  $SIN = 239$
>  
>        239 *
>         39
>        ---
>        9321  - wrong. there are only 4 digits
>  This is not good
>  
>  
>  For $SIN = 32N$ the biggest possible value is
>  
>  
>        329 * 
>         29
>      -----
>       9541  - wrong. there are only 4 digits
>  
>  Again, not good.
>  
>  so [S, I] can be [2, 4] or [4,2]
>  
>  For $SIN = 243$
>
>         243*
>          43
>         ---
>         729 - this should be 4 digits
>        ???
>       -----
>       ???? -
>  
>  For $SIN = 247$
>
>         247*
>          47
>         ---
>        1729
>        988
>       -----
>       11609- this results in I = 0 so it's wrong
>
>  For $SIN = 248$
>
>         248*
>          48
>         ---
>        1984
>        992
>       -----
>       11904 - this results in L = I so it's wrong
>
>  FOR $SIN=249$
>
>         249*
>          49
>         ---
>        2241
>        996
>       -----
>       12201 - this results in E = V so it's wrong
>
>  For $SIN = 423$
>
>         423*
>          23
>         ---
>        1269
>        846
>       -----
>        9729 - it should have 5 digits so it's wrong
>
>  For $SIN = 427$
>
>         427*
>          27
>         ---
>        2989
>        854
>       -----
>       11529 - we have a winner.
>
>  For $SIN = 428$
>
>         428*
>          28
>         ---
>        3424
>        856
>       -----
>       11984 - this results in N = I which is wrong.
>
>  For $SIN = 429$
>
>         429*
>          29
>         ---
>        3861
>        858 - this means U = S so it's wrong
>       -----
>       ?????